# Changing button class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the below button is clicked it, the javascript code checks if the class is btn-default, which it is and the javascript changes the class from "btn btn-default" to btn btn-success, but when I click the button again it calls the javascript code below again even that the button class has been changed from btn-default.

code on page:

```
<div class=vote>
      <button type="button" id="test"  type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></button>
```

javascript:

```
  $(".vote").find(".btn-default").click(function () {
     button_id =  this.id;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/vote',
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'word_id': button_id
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if ((data.errors)){
                  $('.error').removeClass('hidden');
                    $('.error').text(data.errors.name);
                }
                else {
 $('#'+button_id).removeClass('btn btn-default').addClass('btn btn-success');

                }
```

Comment: Why not just `.vote .btn-default`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the event is still attached even after the class changes.

You can prevent this by making use of event delegation:

```js
$(".vote").on('click', ".btn-default", function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    $(this).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-success');
});
```

```css
.btn-default {
  background-color: blue;
}

.btn-success {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=vote>
  <button type="button" id="test" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up">Thumbs Up</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" id="test" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down">Thumbs Down</span>
  </button>
</div>
```